# Macro behavior in function

Tags: c, function, macros, c-preprocessor

I expected output for the below program as 10 20 but it is 10 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define i 10

int main()
{
printf("%d\t",i);
fun();
printf("%d",i);
return 0;
}

fun(){
    #undef i
    #define i 20
}
```

If I assume like if a function call `fun()` returned back to `main()` then the original `i` value is printed then again I am wrong by looking at the output the below program,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define i 10

fun(){
    #undef i
    #define i 20
}

int main()
{
printf("%d\t",i);
fun();
printf("%d",i);
return 0;
}
```

Expected output: 10 20 but the output is: 20 20

Can anybody please explain me the behaviour?

Comment: The clue is in the name of the component that handles macro's: the **pre**-processor: macro's are expanded during compilation, not at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#define` is a preprocessor MACRO. The value is substituted at compile time instead of runtime.

So, the processing happens as per the presence (sequence) of the `#define`s. That means, you cannot expect the `#undef` and `#define` to work on runtime.

To elaborate, your case 1 code looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define i 10

int main()
{
printf("%d\t",10);
fun();
printf("%d",10);
return 0;
}

fun(){
    #undef i
    #define i 20
}//now i is 20, but no one is using it, at compile time
```

and, your second code looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define i 10

fun(){
    #undef i
    #define i 20   // i get a new definition here
}

int main()
{
printf("%d\t",20);
fun();
printf("%d",20);
return 0;
}
```

---

A note: The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: If this is the case, in the first program when the code is compiled why didn't "i" value become 20 ? 
In compile time function "fun" is also evaluated right ?

Comment: @vidya Don't forget, the function is "called" at runtime. At compile time, it's just the source code, nothing else. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I think OP is confused by the fact that his second snippet redefined the macro `i` to `20`, even though the `#define` is inside a function body

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I understand, but how to express it better? Can you suggest something which will clear up any confusion?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Perhaps a white lie: The OP could think of the preprocessor as an interpretter (like bash or something): it works sort-of top down, replaces all the macro's it knows when it encounters them. If an existing macro is defined again, it'll replace all the subsequent occurrences by the latest definition it knows (LiFo expansion sort of thing). Just throwing out some analogies/suggestions that hopefully could clear this up for the OP...

Answer (score 1):

One of the very first steps when compiling is to replace all the PREPROCESSING TOKENS with their value. So the evaluation is done at compile time, not at run-time.

So what you get for your first example is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("%d\t",10); // we have only seen define i 10 until now
  fun();
  printf("%d",10); // we have only seen define i 10 until now
  return 0;
}

fun(){
  // the two in here would have made any i after this location be replaced with 20
}
```

And similar for your second case.